# Is there any alternative to window.open to print a PDF? (dialog to print the PDF)

Tags: javascript

I have to open a PDF and ask to print it **automatically**. I did this:

```
const pdfWindow = window.open("generate_pdf.php?id="+id, "_blank");
if (!pdfWindow) {
    alert("You have to enable popups");
} else {
    pdfWindow.addEventListener("load", function () {
        pdfWindow.print();
    }, false);
}
```

this is working correctly, `window.open` opens the link that output the PDF, then when the page loaded, it calls `pdfWindow.print();` that open the dialog to print the PDF.

The problem is that browsers default have popup disabled. So most users will see "You have to enable popups" alert, because window.open will fails. I know popups can be easily enabled, but this is not nice for most users :(

Is there an other solution instead of window.open to:
Open "generate_pdf.php". Then, when "generate_pdf.php" generated the PDF, **automatically** ask to print it.

I used window.open because user should to remain on the main page.

Edit:
The reason why I have to automatically open the print dialog is because I want to be sure that operators will not forget to print the PDF

Comment: Open it in an iframe.

Comment: Why not let the user decide if they a) want to open a new window with the PDF and b) want to print it?

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes it would be the best solution but this web app is not "for all user", it is a web application for an intranet. We would like to automatically open print dialog because operators must to print that PDF, so we want to be sure they will not forget to print it

Comment: @KJ sorry, I didn't undestand your first comment

Comment: @bitifet do it need to be opened in a new window anyway? I mean, I have to window.open in a link that show the PDF in an iframe and then print the iframe

Comment: Ah, well, the question didn't mention that... I would suggest writing a browser extension for that then, because the browser itself *is* written for all users and therefore protects their privacy (and their printer toner and paper).

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes I'm sorry, I edited the question. Sadly I don't think I have time to learn and write the browser extension. If there isn't any solution, we will just enable popups in every operators computer (it will be annoying, but if it is the only solution we will) so that window.open will works without any issues.

Comment: @gotali4396 No: You just need to place the iframe in your document and load its contents through src attribute and then print after onload event. In case you don't want to see loaded pdf you just need to hide that iframe via css. Nothing tested of course! But it should work if I'm not wrong...

Comment: @K J It does work. You just need proper css for @media print media query so that everything outside it is "display: none" and the iframe itself is 100vh height and 100vw width.